# Problem with Terraform autoscaling group tagging

Tags: terraform

on terraform 0.11.4 and terraform provider 2.64.0, when I use tag blocks in the aws_autoscaling_group resource, I get no diffs
If I use null data source, it gets me diff in every plan:

```
common_tags = {
    Name           = "fooname"
    DU             = "foo"
    Pod            = "bar"
    Core           = "2foo"
    Environment    = "2bar"
    Function       = "foo func"
    CreatedBy      = "foo bar"
    Terraform      = true
    TerraformStack = "foo-stack"
  }
```

```
variable "common_tags" {
  type        = "map"
  description = "Tags applied to all applicable resources"
}
```

```
data "null_data_source" "tags" {
   count = "${length(keys(var.common_tags))}"

   inputs = {
    key                 = "${element(keys(var.common_tags), count.index)}"
    value               = "${element(values(var.common_tags), count.index)}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
    }
 }
```

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_autoscaling_group" {
    tags = ["${data.null_data_source.tags.*.outputs}"]
}
```

when I use null data source to pass the list of tags ash terraform resource it gives me diffs in every run. If I use tag blocks it won't give me the diff

output:

```
    module.vci_ims.aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_autoscaling_group
           tags.1318442105.%:                   "0" => "3"
           tags.1318442105.key:                 "" => "TerraformStack"
           tags.1318442105.propagate_at_launch: "" => "1"
           tags.1318442105.value:               "" => "foo-stack"

           tags.1944474220.%:                   "3" => "0"
           tags.1944474220.key:                 "TerraformStack" => ""
           tags.1944474220.propagate_at_launch: "true" => ""
           tags.1944474220.value:               "foo-stack" => ""
```

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it is a [mcve] please? You should also make sure to show the input to `var.common_tags` so that people can understand what data you are providing to the resource.

Comment: I think the brackets ```[``` and ```]``` in ```tags = ["..."]``` are not needed and might cause some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Just to better understand: Why do you use the ```null_data_source```? Could you not simply put ```tags = local.common_tags```?